# Convergence of a sequence with integer part and fractional part

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers so:

i)  $ x_{n+2}\geq [x_{n+1}] + \{ x_{n} \}$, $n\geq 1$, and
 ii) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }(x_{n+1}-x_{n})=0$.

Prove that  the sequence is convergent.

Comment: what is $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: the fractional part of x_n

Comment: Note that $[x_{n+2}]\ge[x_{n+1}]$. When $x_{k+1}-x_k$ becomes very small, $[x_{k+2}]>[x_{k+1}]$ will violate the first inequality for $n=k+1$. Thus, $[x_n]$ is constant from some place. Then $i)$ is just $x_{n+2}\ge x_n$ for large enough $n$ and $x_n$ is bounded. Take supremums by odd and even indices and prove they cannot be different by $ii)$.

Comment: I can't reach  at a final result using this. Can you please be more detailed?